# Part of Fragment items hides under Action bar

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am learning android dev and my question might be very simple. I am stuck at the below part and requesting your help

**Description**

I am using the android's default "Navigation Drawer" activity to implement a small project. I have created a fragment and when user selects an option from Navigation drawer, the fragment opens.

**Problem faced**

When the fragment opens, part of the fragment & action bar is clipped. Image below[image]

**Code**

**fragment layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_weight="120"
tools:context="test.navigationdrawcheck.RateCalculator">

  <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="12"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:hint="text 1"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorDivider"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="text 2"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorDivider"
    android:ems="12"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="text 3"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorDivider"
    android:ems="12"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="text 4"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorDivider"
    android:ems="12"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Total "
    android:textColor="@color/colorDivider"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="15"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

**App Bar Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="test.navigationdrawcheck.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framecheck"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Actual output i am looking for**

Below is my actual fragment layout xml. **When i merge it with Navigation drawer it should not be clipped** and fragment items should be displayed correctly

[image]

**What I have tried so far**

I tried adding this `android:windowActionBarOverlay=false` in my styles.xml but no luck

Requesting your suggestions

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This might come from the default behaviour of the CoordinatorLayout.
I also assume that you add your fragments in the frameLayout frameCheck.
In your app bar code layout, replace

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/framecheck"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

with :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/framecheck"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Absolutely. That did the trick. Thanks much. Out of Curiosity, how do people do it. I mean do they use the default coordinatorLayout or is there some other way this can be done. Beginners like me might face this issue every time they are going to use the default "Navigation Drawer" activity since it comes with coordinatory layout by default

Comment: Glad to know it solved your issue. As for your question, CoordinatorLayout is used to show/hide the "top content of your activity" when you scroll the content up and down (such as the Google Play Store for example). This create much more immersive apps, and the line that you added is all about notifying the top content about the scroll position of the content view (here, your fragment, which is not scrolled by default).
In case you don't want all this hassle for the moment, you can simply go with a regular FrameLayout and nothing else as the content of your Activity.

Comment: Now that's a neat solution. Thanks@

Answer (score 12):

use `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` 
and add this to your `FrameLayout` of the fragment

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

at leaset worked for me.